# VIMRC # Key Case-Insensitive Search

Tags: vim

I commonly use the # key in VIM to search for text that matches the text under my cursor.  Lately, I have been reading VHDL files which are case insensitive.  Unfortunately for me, the person who originally wrote these files was not consistent with the case of their signals, variables, etc...

Is there a way that I can make the # and * keys be a case-insensitive search?

Answer (score 2):

```
:h 'ignorecase'
```

and

```
:h smartcase
```

are the options you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can set `ignorecase` for the files:

```
set ic
```

or more generally:

```
au FileType,BufEnter *.hdl,*.vhdl set ic
```

As noted, the `ic` option is global and the setting will affect other buffers.
A new mapping (or the remapped <kbd>*</kbd>) can be used to avoid this:

```
map <f5> /\c\<<C-R><C-W>\><CR>
```

Comment: No, `'ignorecase'` is a global option; this will affect all other Vim buffers, too!

Comment: Frankly, I don't know how to remap the `*`. Any ideas?

Comment: And <C-R><C-W> has different meaning compared to original `*`, which is quite complicated. It is probably a better idea to do the original `*`, than add `\c` to the search term by pressing `/` and typing `\c`, followed by `Enter`

Comment: Hmm. Yes, `map` works for `*`, just the search is not saved in the search history. Any idea how to fix that?